# Android inject NavController to fragments using Hilt

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am trying to inject te navController object in my fragments using Hilt.
I have this decleration in every fragment (except for the `mainFragment`):

```
@Inject
public NavController navController;
```

and I have this module to provide the injection:

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent.class)
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @Provides
    public NavController provideNavController(@ActivityContext Activity activity) {
        return Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    Activity provideActivity(Activity activity) {
        return activity;
    }
}
```

and this is how I get the navController in the `mainFragment`:

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
```

(not injecting it)

now this works fine for me, but in production I get many crashes as I see in the crashlytics this error:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
       at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:3496)
       at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$Api28Impl.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:881)
       at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:376)
       at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.kt:48)
       at com.mayapppackage.name.di.module.MainActivityModule.provideNavController(MainActivityModule.java:31)
       at com.mayapppackage.name.di.module.MainActivityModule_ProvideNavControllerFactory.provideNavController(MainActivityModule_ProvideNavControllerFactory.java:46)
       at com.mayapppackage.name.DaggerMainApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ActivityCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerMainApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:954)
       at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
       at com.mayapppackage.name.DaggerMainApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$FragmentCImpl.injectSecondFragmentScreenFragment2(DaggerMainApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:651)
       at com.mayapppackage.name.DaggerMainApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$FragmentCImpl.injectSecondFragmentScreenFragment(DaggerMainApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:545)
       at com.mayapppackage.name.ui.Hilt_SecondFragmentScreenFragment.inject(Hilt_SecondFragmentScreenFragment.java:112)
       at com.mayapppackage.name.ui.Hilt_SecondFragmentScreenFragment.onAttach(Hilt_SecondFragmentScreenFragment.java:62)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1881)
       at com.mayapppackage.name.ui.Hilt_SecondFragmentScreenFragment.onAttach(Hilt_SecondFragmentScreenFragment.java:49)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:3063)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.attach(FragmentStateManager.java:464)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:254)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2884)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1990)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1965)
       at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.kt:169)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3090)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2884)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:252)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:220)
       at com.mayapppackage.name.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8391)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8370)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1403)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3842)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4011)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:111)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2466)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8355)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
```

any idea what cause this crash? how can I inject the Activity to the navController properly?
thanks

Comment: is progaurd enabled in production ?

Comment: not sure, I haven't touched my proguard at all